# Select more than one column and remove NULL values from result

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to create a query in MySQL, but I'm having difficulties. I can already select one column, but would like to select more than one. This is the code I'm using:

```sql
    SELECT
      e.IDCARTEIRA,
      (SELECT `VALORAGUA` FROM `INDICADORES.VW_CADASTRO_HIDROMETROPOLITANO` WHERE `IDCARTEIRA` = e.IDCARTEIRA AND `REFERENCIA_MES_ANO` = '202109') AS 'Ref 09 2021',
      (SELECT `VALORAGUA` FROM `INDICADORES.VW_CADASTRO_HIDROMETROPOLITANO` WHERE `IDCARTEIRA` = e.IDCARTEIRA AND `REFERENCIA_MES_ANO` = '202110') AS 'Ref 10 2021'
      FROM `INDICADORES.VW_CADASTRO_HIDROMETROPOLITANO` e
      GROUP BY e.IDCARTEIRA;
```

**This is the query result:**

```
IDCARTEIRA | Ref 09 2021 | Ref 10 2021
       1   |    39,76    |    (null)
       2   |   (null)    |    174,97
       3   |   (null)    |    (null)
       4   |   388,33    |    (null)
       5   |   (null)    |    (null)
```

But I would like to select more columns, like:

```sql
    SELECT
      e.IDCARTEIRA, e.otherColumn, e.AnotherColumn [...]
```

In addition, I would also like to eliminate null results.

**This would be the expected result (only show rows with non empty Ref 09 2021 and non empty Ref 10 2021 columns)**

```
IDCARTEIRA | OtherColumn |Ref 09 2021 | Ref 10 2021
       1   |     Value   |    39,76   |    N/A  
       2   |     Value   |     N/A    |   174,97
       4   |     Value   |    388,33  |    N/A
```

Does anyone know how I can do these two things?

I tried:

```sql
    SELECT
       e.IDCARTEIRA,
       e.MATRICULA,
       e.LIG_AGUA_SIT,
      COALESCE((SELECT `VALORAGUA` FROM `INDICADORES.VW_CADASTRO_HIDROMETROPOLITANO` WHERE `IDCARTEIRA` = e.IDCARTEIRA AND `REFERENCIA_MES_ANO` = '202109' AND `CONSUMO_FATURADO_MES` - `CONS_MEDIO_AG_6_MESES` > 0),'') AS 'Referencia 09 2021',
      COALESCE((SELECT `VALORAGUA` FROM `INDICADORES.VW_CADASTRO_HIDROMETROPOLITANO` WHERE `IDCARTEIRA` = e.IDCARTEIRA AND `REFERENCIA_MES_ANO` = '202110' AND `CONSUMO_FATURADO_MES` - `CONS_MEDIO_AG_6_MESES` > 0),'') AS 'Referencia 10 2021'
      
      FROM `INDICADORES.VW_CADASTRO_HIDROMETROPOLITANO` e
      GROUP BY e.VALORAGUA ORDER BY e.IDCARTEIRA;
```

**But the row 4 not showing:**

```
4 | 121112 | CORTADO  |  388,33
```

**@FanoFN suggestion:**

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=e6e691dc4c8b4edc17e2446049497123

In the case of the example shown in the link I need only lines 1, 2 and 4 to be displayed. In other words, I need only the non-empty rows of the columns "Ref 09 2021" and "Ref 10 2021" to be displayed.

Comment: You're already selecting more than one column (you have three). Add the additional columns the same way you added the second and third; separate them with a comma from the others. And you can google `IS NOT NULL` for your second question.

Comment: If you `group by e.IDCARTEIRA`, you need to pay attention to the rules about grouping. Read https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-handling.html

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean about eliminating null results. Can you show a hypothetical version of what you'd like your result to be? What should the example above use in place of missing data, where `(null)` appears?

Comment: @Bill Karwin I updated the code.

Comment: Is that a string of zero length, e.g. `''`? You should read about the [COALESCE() function](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_coalesce) which can replace a NULL expression with a default zero length string.

Comment: @Bill Karwin yes, it's a string of zero length. I updated the code again.

Comment: Why did you change from `group by e.IDCARTEIRA` to `GROUP BY e.VALORAGUA`? The result will be reduced to one row for each distinct value of the grouping column.

Comment: @BillKarwin I was trying to display only the non-empty rows of the columns "Reference 09 2021" and "Reference 10 2021" that's why i changed. But it didn't work as expected.

Comment: I think you should read a little more until you understand how GROUP BY works. Any reference manual or technical book on SQL should have that information.

Comment: @BillKarwin You're right. But I would also like some help on how I can tweak my code.

Comment: Can you look at this sample https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=bdd13e143af236dde8cedfc6c5fb5292 and edit accordingly. Once you're done, click "run" and post the link into your question. I purposely add example `202111` and `202112` for `IDCARTEIRA=3,5` and I'm interested in how would you want to handle those data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're just looking for a quick solution on your current attempt then might I suggest doing something like this:

```
 SELECT
      e.IDCARTEIRA,
      COALESCE((SELECT `VALORAGUA` FROM VW_CADASTRO_HIDROMETROPOLITANO WHERE `IDCARTEIRA` = e.IDCARTEIRA AND `REFERENCIA_MES_ANO` = '202109'),'') AS 'Ref 09 2021',
      COALESCE((SELECT `VALORAGUA` FROM VW_CADASTRO_HIDROMETROPOLITANO WHERE `IDCARTEIRA` = e.IDCARTEIRA AND `REFERENCIA_MES_ANO` = '202110'),'') AS 'Ref 10 2021'
      FROM VW_CADASTRO_HIDROMETROPOLITANO e
      GROUP BY e.IDCARTEIRA
HAVING CASE WHEN `Ref 09 2021`='' AND `Ref 10 2021`='' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END=1;
```

Add `HAVING` with `CASE` statement on your custom generated columns. Here's a slightly shorter alternative query:

```
SELECT IDCARTEIRA,
       MAX(CASE WHEN `REFERENCIA_MES_ANO` = '202109' THEN `VALORAGUA` ELSE '' END) AS 'Ref 09 2021',
       MAX(CASE WHEN `REFERENCIA_MES_ANO` = '202110' THEN `VALORAGUA` ELSE '' END) AS 'Ref 10 2021' 
FROM VW_CADASTRO_HIDROMETROPOLITANO
GROUP BY IDCARTEIRA
HAVING CASE WHEN `Ref 09 2021`='' AND `Ref 10 2021`='' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END=1;
```

[Demo fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=67e72396da31c98fd4a9533a91be83bf)