# Oracle SQL - Remove Null rows in aliased results

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

Hi devs I'm developing a small pro bono project that's use oracle sql but I'm not able to hide the null results.

**Table Structure:**

```sql
CREATE TABLE "church-members" (
ID NUMBER(10),
NAME varchar(30)  NOT NULL,
LOGIN varchar(20)  NOT NULL,
PASS  varchar(12)  NOT NULL,
REGISTER_YEAR_MONTH varchar(15)  NOT NULL,
USER_SCORE NUMBER(10),
PRIMARY KEY (ID));
```

**The queries:**

```sql
INSERT INTO "church-members" VALUES
('1', 'John Doe', 'John', 'Xo8*d_d%f58*', '202204','1');

INSERT INTO "church-members" VALUES
('2', 'Mary Doe', 'Mary', 'dLoc&257dsew', '202203','2');

INSERT INTO "church-members" VALUES
('3', 'Robertson III', 'Robertson', 'koIIf59*Liu*', '202203','7');

INSERT INTO "church-members" VALUES
('4', 'Sonia MacDonald', 'Sonia', 'fYhfgtdjfi%', '202204','4');

INSERT INTO "church-members" VALUES
('5', 'Boris Johnston', 'Boris', 'do*&flddkIK%', '202201','2');

INSERT INTO "church-members" VALUES
('6', 'Ruth Henderson', 'Ruth', 'dF6%*&', '202202','2');
```

**The Select:**

```sql
SELECT 
    ID,
    NAME,
    LOGIN,
    MAX(CASE WHEN REGISTER_YEAR_MONTH = '202203' THEN TO_CHAR(USER_SCORE) ELSE '' END) AS "MARCH SCORE",
    MAX(CASE WHEN REGISTER_YEAR_MONTH = '202204' THEN TO_CHAR(USER_SCORE) ELSE '' END) AS "APRIL SCORE "
FROM 
    "church-members" 

GROUP BY 
    ID,
    NAME,
    LOGIN
```

**And the result fiddle:**

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=a4deac5e3eefb17dca97661552458a61

**I got to this point using the information obtained in the answer from this link:**
[Select more than one column and remove NULL values from result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71685294/select-more-than-one-column-and-remove-null-values-from-result)

Looking at the fiddle example, the results with IDs 5 and 6 should not be showing because both are nulls.
But still null results are being shown...

Can anyone help me to solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a `HAVING` clause requiring that each matching ID have at least data for at least one of the two months:

```sql
SELECT ID, NAME, LOGIN,
       MAX(CASE WHEN REGISTER_YEAR_MONTH = '202203' THEN TO_CHAR(USER_SCORE) END) AS "MARCH SCORE",
       MAX(CASE WHEN REGISTER_YEAR_MONTH = '202204' THEN TO_CHAR(USER_SCORE) END) AS "APRIL SCORE"
FROM "church-members"
GROUP BY ID, NAME, LOGIN
HAVING COUNT(CASE WHEN REGISTER_YEAR_MONTH IN ('202203', '202204') THEN 1 END) > 0;
```